# Correctly url encoding a user agent

Tags: python, string, escaping, urlencode

I'm new to Python and seem to be hitting a problem. I'm trying to urlencode a user agent string...

```
import urllib

UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3 Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3'
print 'Agent: ' + UserAgent
print urllib.urlencode(UserAgent)
```

Which results in...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3 Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Source\SomePath\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print urllib.urlencode(UserAgent)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 1254, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I can only assume that although the `UserAgent` is being printed correctly, I'm either missing some string-escaping option on the way in or making a fundamental mistake regarding `urllib.urlencode()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`urllib.urlencode` expects a mapping or sequence with two items each. as can be seen in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

In your code you would need to do the following:

```
urllib.urlencode({'Agent': UserAgent})
```

Comment: Damn, I knew it must be something simple. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Wessie beat me to it. For future reference, you can do this as well:

```
>>> help(urllib.urlencode)
Help on function urlencode in module urllib:

urlencode(query, doseq=0)
    Encode a sequence of two-element tuples or dictionary into a URL query string.

    If any values in the query arg are sequences and doseq is true, each
    sequence element is converted to a separate parameter.

    If the query arg is a sequence of two-element tuples, the order of the
    parameters in the output will match the order of parameters in the
    input.
```

Comment: NP. Also, if you don't know about it already, look at dir(urllib) and dir(urllib.urlencode). dir() makes the unknown unknowns known; help() makes the known unknowns known.

Comment: I didn't so thanks again. I'm familiar with a lot of other languages but need to throw something together in Python for my new xbmc media center - so I've got a grand total of about 3 hours experience :) I've actually managed to get something working already - it's a very powerful and terse language